# blank page example.com/phpmyadmin with errors in browser's console

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm, phpmyadmin, jquery

I have installed phpmyadmin and symlinked it on my LEMP server(php 7).But when i goto hostname/phpmyadmin it returns a blank page with phpmyadmin icon on titlebar.

And 3 errors in browser's console:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: PMA_commonParams is not defined

I have tried many solutions but not able to find whats the problem :(

server config:

```
         server {
   # listen 80 ;
   # listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
     listen 443 ssl default_server;
     listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/laravel/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php  index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

     server_name example.com ;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;


    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

     location /phpmyadmin {

         alias /var/www/laravel/public/;
          index index.php index.html index.htm;
         }


    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

      location ~ \.php$ {
                                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

            include fastcgi_params;
    }


    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
            location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;}


}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
server {
       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
     server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }

     return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Check your error logs (Nginx, PHP) and post relevent portions as part of your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP-FPM in nginx: the buffer of fastcgi is not big enough.

Try adding this to your config:

```
fastcgi_buffers 8 512k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
fastcgi_send_timeout 5m;
fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 5m;
```

My nginx config:

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    listen 80;

    server_name phpmyadmin.dev;

    root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;

    access_log off;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_buffers 8 512k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 5m;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 5m;
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx a ton! it worked. :)